# pop.gmail.com custom CNAME redirect own DNS record (Google Apps)

Tags: domain-name-system, g-suite, gmail, cname-record, pop3

I've been searching everywhere to see if there's a way to get your own URL for Google Apps imap/pop, so users can enter pop.xxxx.com as POP server to get their google apps mail

When I try a CNAME redirect I get a Certificate error in Mail.app

```
pop.xxxx.com. IN CNAME pop.gmail.com.
```

any suggestions?
thanks! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The subject for the certificate used on pop.gmail.com:995 is

```
subject=/C=US/ST=California/L=Mountain View/O=Google Inc/CN=pop.gmail.com
```

There is nothing you can do to change that.  If you are accessing pop.gmail.com using any other name, a client will display a certificate error.

If Google wanted to allow you to use a different name, they would have to allow you to supply your own certificate, and they would have to come up with an IP address or port that is unique to you.  As far as I know they do not support this.

Of course you could also disable certificate warnings in your mail client, but that would be a very bad idea from a security stand point.  You probably just need to accept that you must use `pop.gmail.com`.

Comment: mmm that's what I was afraid for, thx for the excelent answer! :)